# Make Singleton out of Contacts Selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I am getting started with creating singletons out of methods in my app that need to be reused by different viewControllers.

I have here a method that accesses a user's contacts, and allows them to send a message through SMS. This works perfectly, and I now want to turn the code into a singleton that can be accessed by other viewControllers.

This is my code so far. I'm not sure how to begin. Any recommendations would be much appreciated!

**SendSMS.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SMContactsSelector.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface SendSMS : UIViewController

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender;

@end
```

**SendSMS.m**

```
#import "SendSMS.h"

@interface SendSMS ()

@end

@implementation SendSMS

NSMutableArray *phoneArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSString *phoneString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
    stringForKey:@"phoneString"];

    if (!([phoneString isEqualToString:@""])) {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"phoneString"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        //check if the device can send text messages
        if(![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
            UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
            message:@"Your device cannot send text messages" delegate:nil 
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            return;
        }

        //set receipients
        NSArray *recipients = [phoneString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        //set message text
        NSString *message = @"message";
        MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = 
        [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [messageController setRecipients:recipients];
        [messageController setBody:message];

        [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil]; 
    }
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

    SMContactsSelector *controller = [[SMContactsSelector alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"SMContactsSelector" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.requestData = DATA_CONTACT_TELEPHONE; // DATA_CONTACT_ID 
    DATA_CONTACT_EMAIL , DATA_CONTACT_TELEPHONE
    controller.showModal = YES; //Mandatory: YES or NO
    controller.showCheckButton = YES; //Mandatory: YES or NO

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}

- (void)numberOfRowsSelected:(NSInteger)numberRows withData:(NSArray *)data 
andDataType:(DATA_CONTACT)type {

    if (type == DATA_CONTACT_TELEPHONE) {

        for (int i = 0; i < [data count]; i++) {

            NSString *str = [data objectAtIndex:i];                
            str = [str reformatTelephone];
            [phoneArray addObject:str];

            NSString *phoneStringAppended1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
            stringForKey:@"phoneString"];
            NSString *phoneStringAppended2 = [phoneStringAppended1 
            stringByAppendingString: str];
            NSString *phoneString = [phoneStringAppended2 stringByAppendingString:@", 
            "];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:phoneString 
            forKey:@"phoneString"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate methods
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller 
didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult) result {
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled: break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed: break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent: break;
        default: break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not ok to make a viewcontroller singleton.

Take the code you need out in a new class and that should be singleton and accessed by all viewcontrollers.

I'll give you a pattern of singleton

SmsManager.h

```
#import <foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SmsManager : NSObject {
    NSString *someProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someProperty;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

SmsManager.m

```
#import "SmsManager.h"

@implementation SmsManager

@synthesize someProperty;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
      // initialization
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

Just call `SmsManager *smsManager = [SmsManager sharedInstance];` anywere you need